# Python: Rename Armature's "root"

Tags: python, armature

[image]

TWO QUESTIONS:

1- How do I identify the "Sub Armature" shown in green in a Python Script?

2- How do I rename that same item?

This isn't a bone, nor is it the Armature (that's "Korra_Pose" at the top of the image.) It's an invisible or assumed root of the armature, and I don't know how to select or identify it separately from the Armature object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green name is the name of the Armature, while the orange name is actually an object that represents the armature's transform. Since the Armature is thus named 'root', this is how you rename it:

```
import bpy

bpy.data.armatures['root'].name = "NewName"
```